# Have to set border color of edittext android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have used

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
 </shape>
```

and in my Edittext I set this set as background

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
```

I only want to set border color only in order to achieve this, i try to use color in corners but it doesn't allow to compile.

```
<corners
        android:Color="#00ff00"
        android:radius="0dp" />
```

Comment: it doesn't allow to compile....

Comment: there is typo at `android:Color="#00ff00"` in `corners` make `color` in small letter.

Comment: <corners /> tag doesnt support android:Color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:padding="10dp"
   android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
   <stroke
   android:width="2dp"
   android:color="#00ff00" />

</shape>
```